# Object direction relative to itself - Unity C#

Tags: unity-game-engine, vector, coordinates, direction

This 'object' is a rectangle in 2D coordinates. (Game is in Unity 3D)

With `Rigidbody.velocity.z` I can know if the object is moving right or left, but how can I know if this object (a spaceship) is moving to its own right or left?

Imagine a spaceship that accelerates forward. Then after a while the ship rotates 90°, having its right side now aligned with the direction of movement. If then the ship rotates 180°, it will have its left side aligned with the direction it is moving.

I think another way of asking would be, how to know in which side of the ship is the vector of movement?

**Context**

The ship has a maximum speed. If the ship is at maximum speed and it needs to change direction, first it has to slowdown. If the vector of the ships movement is somewhere to its right side, then it has to add a force pushing against it, `rigidbody.addForce (transform.left * force)`

(I haven't written this in the code yet, but below "headed" is the normalized vector of where the ship is headed, and shipDirection is the normalized vector of the ships direction. Supposedly when they match is when ship is pointed at where it is going, but I have to test it first)

```
if (throttle > 0) {
  if (headed != shipDirection) {
    if (body.velocity.z > 0)
      Rigidbody.addForce (transform.right * force);
    if (body.velocity.z < 0)
      Rigidbody.addForce (transform.left * force);
  }
}
```

The problem above is that `transform.right` or `transform.left` can be at either side depending on the object orientation, so it could either speed or slow the ship.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can perform the dot product of the velocity with any directional vector to give the component in that direction. E.g. `Vector2f.DotProduct(Rigidbody.velocity, Rigidbody.right)` will be positive if the object is moving to its own right, and vice versa.

Comment: Just want to add that this is a projection of the vector `Rigidbody.right` onto `Rigidbody.velocity`(assuming i'm reading this correctly)